# Using Youtube video embed with Flickity plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flickity

I have a small gallery powered by [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) plugin that has images and Youtube embed videos in it. The markup is something like:

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-cell">
    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/EXeTwQWrcwY/maxresdefault.jpg">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EXeTwQWrcwY"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

where the preview image sets the size of the cell, and the Youtube iframe being positioned absolutely to cover the cell:

```
> iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
```

The problem is that I can't actually `drag` my carousel when clicking on the video embed because that plays / pauses the video, but keeps the video on the same position, i.e. I can't select it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's a pen with a pretty good (acceptable) workaround here: https://codepen.io/JasonTheAdams/pen/OBPPKW

the SCSS extract:

```
.video-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left :0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  &__grippy {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: calc(50% - 50px);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 2px solid green;
    z-index: 3;

    &:before {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      content: '';
      width: 60%;
      height: 35%;
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
      border: 2px solid green;
    }

    + .video-wrap__grippy {
      left: auto;
      right: 0;
      &:before {
        bottom: 0;
        top: auto;
        right: 100%;
        left: auto;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Not my pen, but I had the same problem and settled on this one.

To unpack it: it creates two divs OVER the video, with :before pseudo classes to create an invislbe area around the play button that then catches the touch interaction.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding `pointer-events: none;` to the iframe?

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` works. Kind of. You can swipe but you can't start the video anymore. So this ist definitely not the best solution :D